# verb of 'remediation' (no such thing as 'remediated')

Tags: word-choice

As in the sentence:

> The pill, in combination with a lot of water, **remediated** the [effects of the] alcohol.

I know there's no such word, only remediation, but I wish it was a word, because it sounds right to me. remedied/weakened/reversed/lessened don't seem as fitting; maybe I'm just attached to the idea of this imaginary word.

Your thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Why isn't "remedied" a good term? ***To remedy***
1. To relieve or cure (a disease or disorder).
2. To counteract or rectify (a problem, mistake, or undesirable situation). http://www.thefreedictionary.com/remedy

Comment: well, at least by google.com's definition it's unflattering: 1. set right (an undesirable situation)

Comment: You can use ***cure***  which is a more common term: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cure. 2 To eliminate (a disease, for example) from the body by medical or other treatment.

Comment: Remedied is a perfectly good word that, I suspect, preceded the inflated version "remediated". Remedy and remedied relate to to remedies, that is to cures. Remediate amd remediation relate to mediation, which although sounding superficially like remedy, are wider and somewhat different terms related to mediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *OED* reports that the verb "remediate", meaning to remedy and a back formation of "remediation", has been with us since 1969.  Here's an example from 1976 in [*Rehabilitation of the Handicapped Programs, 1976: Hearings* [before the US Sentate]](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZiYTAAAAIAAJ&q=%22remediated%22&dq=%22remediated%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMI7qLj3tyExwIVytCACh1WQw3G):

> An Impairment can only be alleviated or **remediated** through devices
>   or medical care. A disability can be **remediated** through training,
>   devices or medical care. A handicapping condition, on the other hand,
>   can be **remediated** through changes in the environment, training of
>   the person, or both.

Comment: I'd add that *to remediate* is quite rare: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=remedy%2Cremediate%2C+remediated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cremedy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cremediate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cremediated%3B%2Cc0. *Remedied vs remediated:* https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=remediate%2Cremediated%2C+remedied&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cremediate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cremediated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cremedied%3B%2Cc0

Comment: What's remarkable in that graph is the continuous decline in usage of "remedied" since 1920! I wonder: what is replacing "remedied" in our lexicon, if "remediated" isn't?